# IIS : global.asa and locale "propagation" to the DLLs

Tags: iis, dll, localization, vb6, global.asa

Having a server running in English (required), we set up its IIS instance with this global.asa sample

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">
    Sub Session_OnStart
        Session.LCID=1036 ' French (standard)
        'Session.LCID=1033 ' English 
    End Sub
</script>
```

It seems that a DLL, especially using the object WinHttp.WinHttpRequest, returns messages in english. Below a sample showing when it occurs :

```
Public Function getHttpResponse(url As String)
  Dim request As New WinHttpRequest

  On Error GoTo errGetHttpResponse
  request.Open "HEAD", url
  request.Send
  getHttpResponse = request.Status
  Exit Function

errGetHttpResponse:
  getHttpResponse = Err.Description ' <-- Right here
End Function
```

Does this mean that IIS doesn't "propagate" global.asa settings to the DLL ?

Comment: There has to be a "place" to set these settings for the DLL somewhere before anything could be propagated from `global.asa` to this "place" IMHO. The most `WinHttp` could do is to get current thread locale (provided that the http request is not done async) -- try setting this too.

Comment: wqw, You mean global.asa is not supposed to have an influence on ActiveX objects ?

Comment: If you were writing an ActiveX object (sic), how would you take care of `Session.LCID` setting? It's possible but doubt that `WinHttp` does it as it's a very IIS specific setting.